# Oracle PL/SQL: assign a new value to an IN variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a procedure defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo (
  AS_OF_DATE_IN IN DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(sysdate)-1
) AS ...
```

Which can be executed in these manners:

```
-- passes '11-NOV-2011'
exec foo('11-NOV-2011');

--set DEFAULT value (yesterday's date)
exec foo();

--makes things more difficult, as default value isn't set
exec foo(NULL);
```

What I want to do is:

```
AS_OF_DATE_IN:=NVL(AS_OF_DATE_IN, TRUNC(sysdate)-1);
```

but it generates a reassignment error.

Other than wrapping all usages of AS_OF_DATE_IN with NVL(), is there a more-efficient way to handle this situation?

** edit **
I made a fairly stupid mistake--I'm writing a procedure, not a function.  The procedure doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a local variable inside the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (
  AS_OF_DATE_IN IN DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(sysdate)-1
) RETURN ??? AS 
    V_AS_OF_DATE DATE DEFAULT NVL(AS_OF_DATE_IN, TRUNC(sysdate)-1);
BEGIN
 ... use V_AS_OF_DATE throughout
END;
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `:=` not `DEFAULT` in your variable declaration. `v_as_of_date DATE := nvl( as_of_date_in, trunc(sysdate)-1 )`

Comment: Well it was mainly lazy copying, but `DEFAULT` works just fine.  What is a problem is the lack of a `RETURN` clause before `AS`!

Comment: Wow!  I had no idea you could use `DEFAULT` in a variable declaration.  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

You have two issues:

1) you are passing in a date vs. a variable.  You can not change the string value that is passed in.

2) You can make the value an "IN OUT" parameter and then you can assign it a value.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FOO (as_of_date in out date) return date
AS
BEGIN
  as_of_date:= nvl(as_of_date,trunc(sysdate)-1);
  return as_of_Date;
END;


-- pass in a null date
DECLARE
   returnDate Date:= null;
BEGIN
   returnDate := foo(null);
   dbms_output.put_line('return date is '|| returnDate) 
END

-- pass in a real date
DECLARE
   returnDate Date:= '01-JAN-2011';
BEGIN
   returnDate := foo(null);
   dbms_output.put_line('return date is '|| returnDate) 
END
```